# Importing vue component into my page Uncaught Exception

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a page which loads the following JS files

- Vue.js
- app.js

The `app.js` file is compiled using webpack, this includes a NPM component from [@chenfengyuan/vue-countdown](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/vue-countdown).

I am trying to display a vue.js countdown component on my page using the following code on my page:

```html
<div class="container" id="app">
  <vue-countdown :time="2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000" v-slot="{ days, hours, minutes, seconds }">
    Time Remaining：@{{ days }} days, @{{ hours }} hours, @{{ minutes }} minutes, @{{ seconds }} seconds.
  </vue-countdown>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/7.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
  import VueCountdown from '@chenfengyuan/vue-countdown';

  // Vue application
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      messages: [],
    },
  });
  app.component(VueCountdown.name, VueCountdown);
</script>
```

When I run this I get a JS error saying:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and how I can correctly import this?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#applying_the_module_to_your_html

Comment: Now I just get an error stating `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@chenfengyuan/vue-countdown". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`. I'm not sure what the correct path is.

Comment: If you're not using a bundler, you need to use a dist version of that library. https://github.com/fengyuanchen/vue-countdown#getting-started. It's also available via CDN: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/@chenfengyuan/vue-countdown

Comment: @J.Titus, i have tried using the CDN reference instead but the import statement error still occurs. I don't quite understand how I'm supposed to resolve it.

Comment: I think you cannot use this @ sign there. Usually when you do this you need some config file mapping the @ sign to a root directory. But here you use it in a normal html file, so I think you must use a proper path for your script import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imports aren't needed, when we reference the script, it'll add it to the page scope. I created a working codepen [here](https://codepen.io/imseaworld/pen/BawdeOa).

I believe the issue you were running into was not including `components`, so you were very close!

```html
<div class="container" id="app">
  <vue-countdown :time="2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000" v-slot="{ days, hours, minutes, seconds }">
    Time Remaining：@{{ days }} days, @{{ hours }} hours, @{{ minutes }} minutes, @{{ seconds }} seconds.
  </vue-countdown>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/7.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@chenfengyuan/vue-countdown@1.1.5/dist/vue-countdown.min.js"></script>

<script>
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
      VueCountdown,
    },
    data: {
      messages: [],
    },
  });
  // This line is not needed
  // app.component(VueCountdown.name, VueCountdown);
</script>
```